# Equivalence of limit notation

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Consider a sequence $\{a_n\}_n$ with $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ $\forall n$. We know that the following expression are equivalent:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n=a \tag{$*$}$$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n-a=0 \tag{$**$}$$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |a_n-a|=0 \tag{$***$} $$

Can we say the same when $a_n \in \mathbb{R}^k$ $\forall n$ and $k>1$? (replacing the absolute value in $(***)$ with the Euclidean distance)?

Comment: Do you have some ideas yourself?

Comment: I think the answer is yes, but I would like to have formal confirmation

Comment: First of all, in my mind ( *** ) is the definition of ( * ) convergence in $\mathbb{R}^k$. If you replace the absolute value by the Euclidean distance.

Comment: Then you can easily prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n -a$ converges to the $0$-vector -the $\mathbb{R}^k$ counterpart of $0$- using the hint I gave as an answer.

Comment: Is $k$ finite here?

Comment: yes it is finite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sequences $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $\mathbb R^k$, the relation $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$ is defined as meaning

$$\forall\varepsilon>0\  \exists N\in\mathbb N\  \forall n\ge N\  |a_n-a|<\varepsilon.$$

Therefore $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (a_n - a) = 0$ is defined as meaning

$$\forall\varepsilon>0\  \exists N\in\mathbb N\  \forall n\ge N\  |(a_n-a)-0|<\varepsilon,$$

and one need only consider how to simplify the expression $(a_n-a)-0$.

The equality $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} |a_n - a| = 0$ is defined as meaning

$$\forall\varepsilon>0\  \exists N\in\mathbb N\  \forall n\ge N\  ||a_n-a|-0|<\varepsilon.$$

Here again, just think about how to simplify $||a_n-a|-0|<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the fact that $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in every component.